# all.equal() with integer64 data type

Tags: r, integer64

I have two data frames, each with a column of `integer64` type. When I compare the data frames using `all.equal()`, I get `TRUE`, even when the values are wildly different:

```
library(bit64)
original <- data.frame("a" = as.integer64(c(2, 3, 6)), "b" = c("second", "data", "column"))
new <- data.frame("a" = as.integer64(c(2, 30000, 6000001)), "b" = c("second", "data", "column"))
all.equal(original, new)
# TRUE
```

I know that `all.equal()` can accept non-exact matching (e.g. with rounding) and that for scrupulously exact matching `identical()` is the safer choice, but why does `all.equal()` say that these two data frames are the same? Is there a way to get a comparison of the data frames with the useful details of `all.equal()` but while rejecting these two tables as equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that:

```
R> library(bit64)
R> original <- data.frame(a=as.integer64(c(2, 3, 6)), 
+                         b=c("second", "data", "column"))
R> new <- data.frame(a=as.integer64(c(2, 30000, 6000001)), 
+                    b=c("second", "data", "column"))
R> all.equal(original, new)
[1] "Component “a”: Mean relative difference: 669999"
R>
```

What version of `bit64` are you running?

Comment: That was it, thank you! I had version 0.9.7 for some bizarre reason - I've updated to 4.0.5 and now I get the expected 'Component “a”: Mean relative difference: 669999.1'

Comment: I think it was in fact a bug in  the older version that is now squashed.